# Freeform Entries for single use

Tags: solspace-freeform, json

I've built a pretty standard-fare Freeform contact-form, but have spiced things up a bit. The `entry_id` from the JSON-response is used to fetch someone's name and e-mail, which I run through an underscore template and parse out to the user (something along the lines of "Thanks John Doe, we'll get back to you shortly on johndoe@gmail.com).

Now, I understand that this is potentially a *huge* security risk, as all freeform-results are available through a public json-endpoint (in my case `/api/response/{entry_id}`).

How would I go about securing this? Ideally I'd just want the system to only be able to do this once... Is there a way to set that up in Freeform?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're submitting the form via ajax and updating the content of the existing page(?), you could skip the complication of fetching the Freeform entry data and instead take the name and email address values directly from the DOM (the input elements) instead of the POST data, then inject them into the thank-you message content.

If you're using jQuery you could use the `beforeSend` method to store the values and display them in the `success` method.

Comment: I'm aware that I could go this way, I'm just over-architecting the hell out of this thing and actually using the response to instantiate a new `Backbone.Model` and rendering a `Backbone.View` with it.

Comment: I'm thinking of storing the XID of the original form along with the entry and in session, and using that in `{exp:freeform:entries search:entry_xid='={segment_4}'}, so that if they're not matched it won't result anything. Will write up about it later...

Comment: A session cookie to store some flashdata would be my next choice. You can create them really easily with Stash.